# B2C Custom Policy for Acceptance of Terms of Use

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using the following [policy](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-sign-up-versioned-tou/policy) for Terms of use acceptance on signup-signin.

I have it running OK, but the actual terms are not being displayed to the user. How is this supposed to work? Does anyone know how I can insert the terms so the user cna read them first before providing consent?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use custom html to add your own text onto the page.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Or create a paragraph claim and display it on the page using an output claim in your technical profile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#add-a-claim-to-the-user-interface

Comment: Terms and Condition example is half cooked example. Its like we have provided only this part, rest of the main example like displaying the text or adding the URL. You google it on your own or read the documentation and understand on your own